# Check if text in form is correct, and if so, go to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to see if there is a way to do this without JS, and if not, then to make it as easy as possible.

I have a form (sort of like a password form, but not really) and I want to make it so that if the typer types in a certain thing (aka something like "password1") they are sent to a page with information. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Without javascript you can use [required attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) which only checks that is not empty, else you need to use javascript

Comment: Please visit the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and read [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 allows to make simplest validation using so attributes as `required`, `type`, `pattern`, `maxlength`, `min`, `max`, `step` and others (see [HTML Input Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp) and [HTML  type Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) for details). If you need to use a complex logic, then use JavaScript or server-side validation.